# c# click on html button

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, button, webbrowser-control

Im loading an external website in webbrowser control and trying to click a button:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="rlg-btn-primary" value="Save changes"/>
```

whit this c# code:

```
var elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT");

foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
{
    if (elem.GetAttribute("value") == "Save changes")
    {
        elem.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

the problem is that nothing happens. no error message. the page just sits still and nothing happens. I believe the code is correct. any thoughts? thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask what are you trying to do or what did you want to achieve? Did you want to do a `click` to the button and trigger the `click` event in the server side? If yes, what tools did you use for the `C#` code? Did you use 'VisualStudio' for that?

Comment: @Kyojimaru yes im using visual studio and yes i want to trigger the click event on the server side.

Comment: @xicocana if I am not mistaken you are loading an external website in webbrowser control and trying to click a button right ? Why I am asking this is the answers and comments are far different from question.

Comment: @Kris thats exactly that ! i should have more more explicit thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert it to HTMLButtonElement and click like below

```
 HTMLButtonElement btnele = (HTMLButtonElement)ele.DomElement;
 btnele.click();
```

To get that you need to add Microsoft.mshtml reference. I use the below helper class which may help you further

```
public static class HtmlElementHelper
    {
        public static string Val(this WebBrowser wb, string id, string Val = null)
        {
            HtmlElement ele = wb.Document.GetElementById(id);
            if (ele.IsNotNull())
            {
                HTMLInputElement txtele = (HTMLInputElement)ele.DomElement;
                if (Val.IsNull())
                    Val = txtele.value;
                else
                    txtele.value = Val; 
            }
            return Val;
        }
        public static void eleClick(this WebBrowser wb, string id)
        {
            HtmlElement ele = wb.Document.All[id];
            if (ele.IsNotNull())
            {
                switch (ele.TagName.ToLower())
                {
                    case "input":
                        HTMLButtonElement btnele = (HTMLButtonElement)ele.DomElement;
                        btnele.click();
                        break;
                    case "a":
                        HTMLAnchorElement ancele = (HTMLAnchorElement)ele.DomElement;
                        ancele.click();
                        break;
                } 
            }
        }
        public static void eleClick(this WebBrowser wb, string tag, string data)
        {
            HtmlElementCollection eleCollection = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName(tag);
            foreach (HtmlElement ele in eleCollection)
            {
                if (ele.InnerHtml.ToCString().ToLower() == data)
                {
                    switch (tag)
                    {
                        case "a":
                             HTMLAnchorElement ancele = (HTMLAnchorElement)ele.DomElement;
                            ancele.click();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public static string Html(this WebBrowser wb, string id, string val = null)
        {
            HtmlElement ele = wb.Document.GetElementById(id);
            if (ele.IsNotNull())
            {
                switch (ele.TagName.ToLower())
                {
                    case "span":
                        HTMLSpanElement spanEle = (HTMLSpanElement)ele.DomElement;
                        if (val.IsNull())
                            val = spanEle.innerHTML;
                        else
                            spanEle.innerHTML = val;
                        break;
                    case "div":
                        HTMLDivElement divEle = (HTMLDivElement)ele.DomElement;
                        if (val.IsNull())
                            val = divEle.innerHTML;
                        else
                            divEle.innerHTML = val;
                        break;
                } 
            }
            return val;
        }
        public static string Style(this WebBrowser wb, string id)
        {
            HtmlElement ele = wb.Document.All[id];
            return ele.Style.ToCString();
        }
        public static string Attr(this WebBrowser wb, string id, string key, string val=null,bool isTag=false,string data =null)
        {
            if (!isTag)
            {
                HtmlElement ele = wb.Document.All[id];
                if (val.IsNull())
                    val = ele.GetAttribute(key);
                else
                    ele.SetAttribute(key, val); 
            }
            else
            {
                HtmlElementCollection eleCollection = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName(id);
                foreach (HtmlElement ele in eleCollection)
                {
                    if (ele.InnerHtml.ToCString().ToLower().Contains(data))
                    {
                        switch (id)
                        {
                            case "a":
                                if (val.IsNull())
                                    val = ele.GetAttribute(key);
                                else
                                    ele.SetAttribute(key, val);
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return val;
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply! i ll try that as soon as I figure out this other problem I just found.. my code never gets in the foreach cicle.. any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe the page not fully loaded, some websites load code in JavaScript and Ajax calls. Check the document html to see if the input is there. Some time back when I wrote a Bing bot I used timer to wait for the Dom to load.

Comment: Also try to change the input to lowercase not sure whether it's case sensitive or not, just a thought

Comment: thank u soo much ! i ended up just adding some timmers like u said and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `HTML Tag` provided for that which is `<asp:Button>` (which will render as `<input type="button">`) and not the ordinary `<input type="submit">`

You need to change your `HTML Markup` into this one

```
<asp:Button ID="your_button_id" runat="server" OnClick="your_button_id_Click" />
```

And then in your code behind, don't forget to add

```
void your_button_id_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ... // Your code goes here
}
```

For the `OnClick` event, you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to show the AutoComplete for existing `OnClick` event, or create a new one

Comment: im trying to automatize my interactions with a gamming site.. this is not my page so i cant change the html markup. i should have been more explicit sorry

Comment: Im also very noob at this so maybe I understood ur solution wrong

Comment: @xicocana, sorry about that, I understand your question wrong before, have you tried to `debug` it? Is it ever hit the `elem.InvokeMember("click");`?